# clojure-lsp in neovim is not navigating to function definitions/namespaces

Tags: clojure, neovim, language-server-protocol

I'm using neovim with clojure lsp for clojure development. My neovim config are exactly same as this [repo](https://github.com/rafaeldelboni/nvim-fennel-lsp-conjure-as-clojure-ide).

The autosuggesting is working fine with this configuration. But when I like to navigate to function/namespace definitions, it is not working.

For example, I've local repository which it in [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/guestbook) here. Let's say I'm working on the file `src/clj/guestbook/routes/home.clj`. I'm trying to click and navigate to `save-message!` in [line 39](https://github.com/rajcspsg/guestbook/blob/main/src/clj/guestbook/routes/home.clj#L39). But command + click or ctrl + click is not working.

[image: function navigation not working]

Similarly when I try to navigate the namespaces, command + click is enabled as in the below image.

[image: namespace navigation not working]

But when I click the namespace, it open the browser with link `guestbook.middleware` as in the below image.

[image: namespace navigation not working]

**nvim version** -

```
% nvim --version
NVIM v0.9.0-dev-730+g0344bfad0-dirty
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by rnatarajan@ip-10-250-24-51.us-west-2.compute.internal

Features: +acl +iconv +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/neovim/HEAD-0344bfa/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

**clojure-lsp details** -

```
% clojure-lsp --version
clojure-lsp 2022.12.09-16.00.34-nightly
clj-kondo 2022.12.08
```

Any idea how to make clojure lsp navigation work in neovim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this setup doesn't have any custom bind for the mouse command you using, so probably you getting the default nvim behaviour when ctrl + clicking in the forms.

You probably want `gd` to Go to Definition of a function or namespace, to use it navigate your cursor over an function name or namespace and press `g`and then `d`.

You can check all the presets command listed [here](https://github.com/rafaeldelboni/nvim-fennel-lsp-conjure-as-clojure-ide#settings).

Comment: There is no link in here

Comment: Hey I just tested and CTRL+Click is working fine, I did a clean setup following [this](https://github.com/rafaeldelboni/nvim-fennel-lsp-conjure-as-clojure-ide#how-to-use) and cloned your repo and ctrl+clicked the function and the namespace in question and it navigated fine.

Could you post the nvim and clojure-lsp versions installed in your system?
I recommend nvim v0.8.2 and the latest clojure-lsp for the best experience.

Comment: @RajkumarNatarajan could you try `cat home.clj` and then ctrl+click? I think it would still take you to the browser. This is the terminal doing it like i said in my answer and not related to nvim or clojure.lsp. nvim in general doesnt have click based jumps out of the box. `guestbook.middleware` does look like a link to the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I think the click that you're doing is your terminal opening up the text as a hyperlink. To go to the namespace or any other definition using clojure-lsp you can try using `:lua vim.lsp.buf.definition()` with the cursor on the symbol.

Comment: Thanks @Rahul De. your suggestion is working